# Calling Ruby classes/scripts from Objective C - is MacRuby an overkill?

Tags: objective-c, ruby, macruby

I want to call certain Ruby libraries (natural language processing) from Objective C ( it's a Mac OSX app). I would like however to keep the most of the programming in Objective C, using Ruby only to use that particular library that is in Ruby.

I looked at MacRuby and it seems, that I would be expected to use Ruby syntax across all the application, while I would rather use ObjC for the most part and just interface to one-two ruby classes.

I realize that I can just call ruby script from command line, but some kind of integration seems much more useful that that.

So the question is - can I achieve the described above flow with MacRuby or should I look into something else?

Comment: Are those Ruby libraries ported to MacRuby, or MRI (anything else than MacRuby)?

Comment: no they are just Ruby, well they use RJB so there is some Java there too (if that matters).

Comment: You need to port those to MacRuby then, first, before being able to use them.

Comment: @KennyM.: AFAIK almost all Ruby code is valid in MacRuby. What kind of porting do you envision?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with MacRuby, but I don't think it will offer much benefit over the other options unless you need to interact very heavily between the two environments. MacRuby is more for interacting with the Objective-C world from Ruby than vice-versa, but it does allow you to freely mix the two languages in your project. To be honest, the simplest answer is just using the system Ruby. If this is unsuitable for some reason, you can use the Ruby C API to talk to the Ruby code. There's an [example of this](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ext_ruby.html#S6) in Programming Ruby.

Comment: can you please explain what do you mean by " just using system Ruby" in my case?

Comment: @Stpn: I mean using an NSTask that runs /usr/bin/ruby with the program you want. That's the option that is the least work if it suits your needs.

Comment: Except that MacRuby provides better Unicode string handling than the bundled system Ruby.